# Docker on Windows gives error when trying to start mysql container

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I'm new on Docker and trying now to create my first docker-compose file.
The apache works so far but i'm struggeling a bit with mysql.

Here is my docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "8083:80"
    volumes:
     - ./public_html/:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
    networks:
     - appnet
  db:
    image: mysql
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    networks:
      - appnet
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
volumes:
  db-data:
networks:
  appnet:
```

The error is:
`[ERROR] [MY-010457] [Server] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.`

I alread tried to remove the volume totally or added a /data at the end. But it gives me all the time the same error. Also Google didn't give me any good hints.

Does someone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out now. I'm running Docker on a Windows Machine, so i had to reset the credentials ond Docker App and type in again. Now it works. Hope that will help others as well. It seems on Docker for Windows, when something not work as expected it make sense to reset the credentials.